# How to solve it in radicals?

Tags: abstract-algebra, polynomials

How to solve the equation $x^5+10x^3+20x-18=0$ in radicals? One of its roots is
$$\frac 1 5\, \left( -\frac1 4- \frac 1 4\,\sqrt {5}+\frac 1 4\,\sqrt {-10+2\,\sqrt {5}}
 \right) \sqrt [5]{28125-3125\,\sqrt {113}}-$$ $$10\,{\frac {-\frac 1 4-\frac 1 4\,
\sqrt {5}-\frac 1 4\,\sqrt {-10+2\,\sqrt {5}}}{\sqrt [5]{28125-3125\,\sqrt {
113}}}}.
$$
It would be a useful example in teaching and learning Galois theory.

Comment: Such a mess won't be an useful example...

Comment: @vonrand: Thank you for the feedback. I find only one your answer in algebra on the first three pages of your answers.

Comment: @user64494 What does that have to do with anything? He's a tenured professor of mathematics; I would take his opinion a little more seriously.

Comment: First off, render $\sqrt[5]{28125-3125\sqrt{113}}=5\sqrt[5]{9-\sqrt{113}}$ to get a simpler form for the known root.

Answer (score 1):

Using [my implementation](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/134551/7288), which is based on Daniel Lazard's paper [*Solving Quintics by Radicals*](http://doi.org/10.1007/978-3-642-18908-1_6), and after some simplification we can represent the roots of your quintic in radicals as follows:
$$\begin{align}
&x_{1,2} = \phi^2\, \gamma \pm i \, \beta, &x_{3,4} = -\gamma \pm i \, \phi\, \beta,  \quad\quad &x_5=\frac{2}{\alpha }-\alpha,\quad\text{where}\\[5mm]
&\phi = \frac{1+\sqrt{5}}2, &\alpha = \sqrt[5]{\sqrt{113} - 9\,},\quad\quad &\beta =\frac{\left(\alpha^2+2\right)\sqrt[4]{5}}{2\, \alpha\,\sqrt{\phi\,}},\quad\quad\gamma =\frac{\alpha ^2-2}{2 \,\alpha\,  \phi }.\end{align}$$

Answer (score 0):

The reason why we might want to use Galois theory is that there is no equation in radicals for an arbitrary degree $5$ polynomial. But evidently you already know a root. Therefore we may use division with remainder to get a degree 4 polynomial. But there is a [known formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quartic_function) for the roots of a degree 4 polynoimal. Perhaps you know this, and also that it is quite long.